# Question about ratios and trigonometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, ratio

If I am only given, in a triangle ABC, that:

$$\frac{a-c}{\cos B}= b(\cos C-\cos A)$$

$$\frac{a-c}{\cos C-\cos A}=\frac{b}{\cos B}$$

Would I be able to assume that

$$\frac{a}{\cos C}=\frac{c}{\cos A}=\frac{b}{\cos B} \,?$$

Since ratios like

$$\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=k$$

are usually handled this way

$$\frac{x-y}{a-b}=\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=k$$

In a question, I had to determine the nature of a triangle given the first equation at the very top, I successfully deduced that it was an isosceles triangle using the method mentioned above with the sine rule but I was told that it was incorrect. If so why?

Answer (score 1):

no you can't.

for example, we have

$\frac{7-5}{9-5}=\frac{1}{2}$

but we don't have

$\frac{7}{9}=\frac{5}{5}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Should've thought of that...thanks anyway!